# Pipelined/Superscalar performance code Segmentation fault

Tags: c, architecture, segmentation-fault, pipeline

i am working on this code in C which calculates and charts the total number of cycles on a 6 stage pipe-lined and super-scalar architecture.
The code compiles fine but when i run it i get a segmentation fault.

i get a segmentation fault in this option. I enter my selection as 1 and then i enter the total cycles to be 5. Also the user should input the instruction for example as
r0 = r1 + r2 but i am not sure how to prompt that

```
 void EnterInst(){
   char instr_string[9];
   int i;
   printf("Enter total number of instructions: ");
   scanf("%d\n", n);

  set = (instr*) malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(instr)); 
  set[0].dest = -1;

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  printf("%d", i);
  scanf("%s", instr_string);
  set[i].dest = instr_string[1]-'0';
  set[i].src1 = instr_string[4]-'0';
  set[i].src2 = instr_string[7]-'0';
 }
}
```

i also get another segmentation fault when i select 2 as my selection. The code that follows is for the second option

```
void pipelined(){
int overlap = 0;
int delay =0;

set[1].delay = 0;

int i;
for(i = 2; i <= n; i++){
  if((set[i-2].dest == set[i].src1) || (set[i-2].dest == set[i].src2)){
     if(overlap == 0){
        delay = 1;
        overlap = 1;
     }
     else{
        delay = 0;
        overlap = 0;
     }
  }//if RAW dep.
  else{ overlap = 0; }

  if((set[i-1].dest == set[i].src1) || (set[i-1].dest == set[i].src2)){
     delay = 2;
     overlap = 1;
  }
  set[i].delay = delay + 1 + set[i-1].delay;
 }//end for-loop
 //calculate total delay
 total_delay = set[n].delay;
 printf("Total number of cycles: %d", total_delay);
 printf("%d",print_Chart());
}
```

I would really like to know why the segmentation fault happens and how i can fix it. This is really troubling me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if(overlap = 0)` should be `if(overlap == 0)`.

Comment: in which lines does the **segfault** occur? have you tried using _gdb_?

Comment: the EnterInst function only allows for 9 characters in the instruction string, including the nul terminator byte. but the example instruction is 12 bytes plus the nul terminator

Comment: regarding this line: scanf("%d\n", n);  there are a few problems: 1) for most calls to scanf, the format string should include a leading ' ' (space) so that white space in the input stream are consumed (for instance, newline). 2) the returned value from input functions (like scanf) needs to be checked to assure all input conversions are successful  3) the variable 'n' is not defined. 4) with scanf, input variables must be address of, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
suggest showing definition of 'n' and 'instr'
as that would greatly help with the debugging.

this line: char instr_string[9];
only has room for 8 characters plus the string terminator
however, the example input is 12 characters plus the string terminator
this is undefined behaviour and probably is 
the root cause of the seg fault event in the EnterInst() function


set[i].dest = instr_string[1]-'0'; <-- gets 0x30 - 0x30 so set[i].dest = 0
set[i].src1 = instr_string[4]-'0'; <-- gets 0x20 - 0x30 so set[i].src1 = -16
set[i].src2 = instr_string[7]-'0'; <-- gets 0x20 - 0x30 so set[i].src2 = -16

that is probably not what you want.

however, scanf stops on any white space (like a space and newline), so this line:

scanf("%s", instr_string);

will fail to input anything beyond the "r0"

therefore, the next calls, in the loop, to scanf will get nothing.

The above is a very good reason to always check the returned code from any 
input function and to use a leading ' ' in scanf format strings

suggest using fgets to input a whole line into a buffer
then parse the data from that buffer 

for several reasons, the returned value from the malloc family
should not be cast
I.E. 
set = (instr*) malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(instr));
should be:
set = malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(instr));
and the returned value should be checked, I.E.
if( NULL == (set = malloc ((n+1) * sizeof(instr)) )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

the code might prompt as follows for the instruction:
int regValue = -1;
do
{
    printf( "input destination register number (0...9):" )
    if( 1 != scanf( " %d", &regValue ) )
    {  // then, scanf failed
        perror( "scanf failed for destination register number" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
while( (0 <= regValue) && (9 >= regValue) );
set[0].dest = regValue;

with similar statements for the other registers, and the operator

the variable 'set' is a action verb, probably good as the first part of 
a function name, but does not give a good representation
of a variable name, especially as it yields no indication
of its' contents.

in C, array references begin with 0 and end with 1 less than the array size
so to avoid skipping the first 'instr' entry in the 'set' array of structs
use:

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ rather than: for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
```